# No output from grep -P 'com\K\w+'

Tags: text-processing, grep, regular-expression

I have a source file saved off the internet which has various links I want to pull data from. For example `https://blahblah.com/uniquetext`

I'm using

```
grep -oP 'com\K\w+' source.txt > list.txt
```

but I just get an empty text file. What am I doing wrong exactly? Have I misunderstood how the command works?

My input text (the source file O assume) is very messy and practically unreadable, it's a .html converted to .txt, if that makes a difference.

What it looks like:

```
gs="evt">window.open('https://twitter.com/warrenarend', '_blank');</script></button><button dojoType="dijit.form.Button" type="button">26. patriotpariah<script type="dojo/method" event="onClick" args="evt">window.open('https://twitter.com/patriotpariah', '_blank');</script></button><button dojoType="dijit.form.Button" type="button">27. teutates1989<script type="dojo
```

What I want:

```
twitter.com/patriotpariah
twitter.com/warrenarend
…
```

Comment: We have no idea what you're doing wrong unless you show us your input text. You almost certainly don't want `\w+` but everything depends on the input. When asking this type of question, you need to show us your input and your desired output. If you're trying to match `uniquetext`, use `grep -oP '\.com/\K\w+'`.

Answer (score 1):

`\w` match "word" symbols (letters, digits and underscore) but in your example there is `/` after `com` which is not `:alnum:` so your pattern match nothing == empty output.

You can add `/` to pattern and look what is happend:

```
grep -oP 'com/\K\w+'
```

FYR `-P` option is experimental and can do which not expected in more systems, so you can do your task in other way:

```
sed "/com/s/.*\/\(\w\+\).\?$/\1/"
```

Comment: ok thank you i use the sed command and got abit closer to my goal using `sed -n "/twitter.com/,/blank/p" ` but i am still getting other text in the file that is not between those two patterns.

Comment: `\?` is also a GNU extension. Use `\{0,1\}` portably.

Comment: @roshan For such search is better to use `grep` : `grep -o "twitter.com/[^' ]\+"`